# Windows Bat - The System Cannot Find the File Specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I am using the following code in a .bat to cleanup a directory. It is to delete any directory with a time stamp older than 14 days. The thing is, this script works and deletes the appropriate directories. However it returns the error:
`ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified` I am unable to decipher the cause of this, and would like to get to the bottom of it.

```
FORFILES /S /D -14 /p %cd% /M "*" /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rmdir @path /s /q"
```

Comment: Can you show the log file?

Comment: This is just a guess.  I am going to assume that FORFILES enumerates all the directories it has to find first.  Then it passes them onto the cmd that needs to be executed.  So because you used the /S option it enumerated a sub-directory that existed in a parent directory that you already deleted.

Comment: It also appears as if you are using both **`/P`** and **`/M`** for no reason, so perhaps using `FORFILES /S /D -14 /C "CMD /C IF @ISDIR==TRUE IF EXIST @PATH  RD /S /Q @PATH"` would be better.

Comment: Got this to work based on @Squashman comment. And @Compo is correct that i do not need the /p or /m... Here was the code that worked.. `FORFILES /D -14 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rmdir @path /s /q"`. Is there a way to now also query the files nor not only the date but say for directory names that contain only numbers... I will update question to represent this.

Comment: There is no regular expression support in `FORFILES`.

Comment: @LCaraway You shouldn't update a question with another question, you should write a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

As to the follow up question you asked:

Using a Windows batch file, find directories that do not contain any letters in their name.  They can contain special characters and spaces.  Delete the directories and their sub-folders w/o confirmation.

Put `1.bat` in the directory you want to cleanup.  Open a cmd window and run 1.bat.

1. Find all directories that do not contain any letters in their name and output their names to 1.txt. They can contain special characters and spaces.
2. Echo the directories to be removed.  Do not remove them.
3. Remove comment tag to remove directories and sub-directories w/o confirmation.

   `1.bat
   for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%a in ('DIR /b /ad ^| findstr /v /r "[a-Z]"') do echo "%cd%\%%a" will be removed without confirmation.
   :: for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%a in ('DIR /b /ad ^| findstr /v /r "[a-Z]"') do rd /s /q "%cd%\%%a"`

[image: Nothing removed]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: Removed]